# Equation inside \framebox giving errors

Tags: equations, align, boxes

I have the following code:

```
\framebox{
  \begin{align*}
    Something here
  \end{align*}
}
```

which gives the following errors:

1. Missing `\endgroup` inserted
2. Missing `}` inserted
3. LaTeX Error: `\begin{document}` ended by `\end{align*}`
4. Missing `$` inserted
5. Display math should end with `$$`
6. Extra `\endgroup`
7. Too many `}`s

I'm new to Latex and don't understand why this is happening. Is this a Latex bug? How can I put an equation inside a box?

Comment: Another alternative to the ones in the existing answer: `empheq`.

Comment: if only a simple box is wanted, `amsmath` has `\boxed{ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} }`.  must be used in math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug, user error. `\framebox` is like `\mbox` and is a single line (horizontal mode) construct, `align` is a display construct that needs to be in vertical mode.  There are several packages for boxed vertical material: mdframed and tcolorbox for example, or simply use

```
\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{\begin{align}....\end{align}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so here is an example :
firstly  use package    `\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}`

```
\begin{align}
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}} \\ 
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}}
\end{align}
```

remove * and put `\Aboxed` .

Output:

[image]

here is my full code:

```
\documentclass[
    german,
    paper=a4,
    ]{scrbook}              %KOMA-
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}} \\ 
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think we don't have to define Aboxed .

Comment: `\Aboxed` is defined by `mathtools`

Comment: Sir, I respect you but my code is perfectly working. we can use package instead defining Aboxed

Comment: My comment was before you had posted code, your edit showed where it was defined, in mathtools, which you had not mentioned in the original answer:-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to box the equations, but this cannot be done that way, because `\framebox` doesn't support line breaks (directly).

You can avoid having to guess the width of the box by building the alignment beforehand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for the example

\newsavebox{\boxedalignbox}
\newenvironment{boxedalign*}
  {\begin{equation*}\begin{lrbox}{\boxedalignbox}$\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}$\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\boxedalignbox}}\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{boxedalign*}
a &= b(x+y)\\
  &= bx+by
\end{boxedalign*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why bother with this?  `amsmath` has `\boxed`, into which an `aligned` environment fits admirably.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Instead of `\fbox` one might want some different ornamentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to have any custom box for any equation environment with `empheq.  Needless to load`amsmath`, as it loads`mathtools, which loads `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand\mybox[2][black]{\fboxrule=1pt\fboxsep=1.2ex\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{\enspace#2\enspace}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box={\mybox[IndianRed]}]{align}
    (x + y)^3 & =x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3t\\%
    x^3 + y^3 & = (x + y)(x^2-xy + y^2)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]